# JavaScript Manipulation of DOM Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table which I want the first column to not move when I am scrolling horizontally. This code below works great for the first column of td's but does not work for the tr's. I have stepped through the code and it all appears to set the values I am expected, but the tr cell does not move with the td cells.

```
window.onscroll = function()
{
    var scrollPosX = window.scrollX;
    var theTable = document.getElementById("tablename"),
    thead = theTable.getElementsByTagName("thead")[0];
    tbody = theTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    hrCell = thead.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
    hrCell.style.left = scrollPosX;
    rCells = tbody.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for(var i = 0; i < rCells.length; i++)
    {
        rCells[i].style.left = scrollPosX;
    }
}
```

JQuery is not an option in this problem as the program I am working on does not support it.

```
<style>
    table
    {
        border: solid black 1px;
    }
    td{
        min-width: 300px;
        border: solid black 1px;
    }

    #run_gen_table td:first-child, #run_gen_table th:first-child
    {
        background-color: white;
        position: relative;
    }
</style>

<table id="tablename">
    <thead id="headname">
        <tr><th>Run No.</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th><th>7</th><th>8</th><th>9</th><th>10</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="bodyname">
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think this is a more HTML/CSS question so you should probably add these in tags

Comment: I think we need to see some html as what you describe doesn't make much sense. Generally speaking `tr`'s are rows that contain `td`'s, which are generally single cells within the row. To achieve first "columns" staying in place usually takes a bit of HTML manipulation. One crude method would create a table for the first column as single row elements and a second for the rest. The second column would then scroll within a div.

Comment: OMG you are right, it's not the tr I need it's the th. Sorry guys

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it but your code would alter all the td elements, not just the first column. A better approach would be to use document.querySelector() to select the first td and th elements.

```
window.onscroll = function()
{
    var scrollPosX = window.scrollX;
    var rCells = document.querySelector("#tablename th:first-child, #tablename td:first-child");
    for(var i = 0; i < rCells.length; i++)
    {
        rCells[i].style.left = scrollPosX;
    }
}
```